# how to delete from selected items of listbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a listbox which contain 6 items . In the seleceted index changed event of list box text of label is changed to the selected item value.Select mode of listbox is multiple.I want
When a user select an item it should remove from listbox and add to label text.
 user can remove the selected items 1 2 or all 
I am not using textbox because i want only listbox items can be select.
my html is

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_mar_cat" runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
<asp:ListBox ID="listbox_mar" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
    CssClass="listbox" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="BulletedList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="Doesn't Matter">Doesn't Matter</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Divorced</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

my server side code is

```
 if (listbox_mar.SelectedValue == "Doesn't Matter")
    {
        lbl_mar_cat.Text = "Doesn't Matter";
    }
    else
    {
        if (lbl_mar_cat.Text == "")
        {
            lbl_mar_cat.Text = listbox_mar.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_mar_cat.Text += ", " + listbox_mar.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your work first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void listbox_mar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listbox_mar.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listbox_mar.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            lbl_mar_cat.Text += listbox_mar.Items[i].Text+ " , " ;
            listbox_mar.Items.Remove(listbox_mar.Items[i]);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: sir can this done without any button click because i dont use any button. Should I use textbox in place of label? I just want to remove the items by clicking on them